# Jenkins, how to run another job few times but with different parameters?

Tags: jenkins

I have a job which is used for precondition, before test execution.

It has functionality for posting offers and searches:

[image]

I have to launch it twice:

- for offers posting
- for searches posting

Of course, parameters for 2 runs is different.

***How to automate those launches, without doing it twice?***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution:

- add new item
- select `Build Flow` type
- select `This build is parameterized`.

I have added all parameters which I will need for launching `MyAnotherJobWhichIWantToRun` two times:

[image]

- Now I have to take those parameters and launch my desired job twice.
  Unneeded parameters set to `0`.

It can be achieved with Groovy script. Just write `Define build flow using flow DSL`:

```
 ignore(ABORTED) {
    ignore(FAILURE) { 
       // offers
        b = build("MyAnotherJobWhichIWantToRun",                   
                 "config.test.timeout.min": params["offers.duration.min"],     

                 "throughput.freight.offer.permin": params["throughput.freight.offer.permin"],
                 "throughput.vehicle.offer.permin": params["throughput.vehicle.offer.permin"],

                 "throughput.freight.search.permin": "0",
                 "throughput.freight.reg.search.permin": "0",
                 "throughput.freight.cnt.search.permin": "0",
                 "throughput.vehicle.search.permin": "0",
                 "throughput.vehicle.reg.search.permin": "0",
                 "throughput.vehicle.cnt.search.permin": "0"
                )
    }
    ignore(FAILURE) {
       // searches
        b = build("MyAnotherJobWhichIWantToRun", 
                "throughput.freight.offer.permin": "0",
                 "throughput.vehicle.offer.permin": "0",

                 "config.test.timeout.min": params["searches.duration.min"],

                 "throughput.freight.search.permin": params["throughput.freight.search.permin"],
                 "throughput.freight.reg.search.permin": params["throughput.freight.reg.search.permin"],
                 "throughput.freight.cnt.search.permin": params["throughput.freight.cnt.search.permin"],
                 "throughput.vehicle.search.permin": params["throughput.vehicle.search.permin"],
                 "throughput.vehicle.reg.search.permin": params["throughput.vehicle.reg.search.permin"],
                 "throughput.vehicle.cnt.search.permin": params["throughput.vehicle.cnt.search.permin"]
                )
    }
}
```

Next blocks:

```
  ignore(ABORTED){
    ignore(FAILURE) {
```

Will start the second job even if first is failing or aborted.